# Set geometry column name in sf::st_write()

Tags: r, postgresql, postgis, r-sf

As of **sf** version [0.9.0](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/blob/master/NEWS.md#version-09-0), `st_write_db()` and `st_read_db()` got defunct. The functions had the nice argument `geom_name = 'wkb_geometry'` which allowed a user to set the name of the simple feature column of the newly created table.

Can I still do this somehow with `st_write()` or do I have to do this in a separate call? E.g. for Postgres: `ALTER TABLE x REANAME COLUMN geometry TO geom;`

Maybe with the `layer_options =`  argument? However I don't know where to look up its possibilities?

---

- Local machine

  - sf_0.9-7 with GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 7.0.0.
- Server

  - **PostgreSQL** 9.6.20
  - **PostGIS**
    POSTGIS="2.3.3 r15473" GEOS="3.7.1-CAPI-1.11.1 27a5e771" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016" GDAL="GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20" LIBXML="2.9.4" LIBJSON="0.12.1" TOPOLOGY RASTER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sf` uses GDAL to read and write data. The GDAL documentation contains for every driver the list of possible layer creation options. For Postgres this can be found under https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html#layer-creation-options

Based on this `layer_options="GEOMETRY_NAME=wkb_geometry"`  should do the trick for you.

Comment: Weird, for me it works: using the `meuse` data from the `sp` the following command `st_write(st_as_sf(meuse), dsn, "meuse_sf", layer_options = "GEOMETRY_NAME=other_geom_name")` saves this in postgis  with `other_geom_name` instead of `wkb_geometry` as expected

Comment: Hm, really strange. First of all, when trying your code above I had to set the `coords = ` argument in `st_as_sf(meuse, coords = c('x', 'y'))` to make it run and secondly it also named my geometry column just "geometry".
I run sf_0.9-7 with GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 7.0.0. Can you tell me your versions? Thanks!

Comment: Just checked the lib versions of the Server where PostgreSQL is running on. Rather old, maybe that's the cause.

Comment: yes this is most likely the issue. On my local machine I have the same versions as you but on the server have the latest versions [POSTGIS="3.1.0 3.1.0" PGSQL="130" GEOS="3.9.0-CAPI-1.14.1" SFCGAL="1.3.8" PROJ="7.1.1" GDAL="GDAL 3.2.0, released 2020/10/26" LIBXML="2.9.9" LIBJSON="0.12" LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1" WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)" TOPOLOGY RASTER]